# Tools for making web applets

Tags: c++, opengl, applet

Iv written a program in C++ that takes a set of n points and two double variables as input and output a graph with some special properties. I also wrote some OpenGL codes to visualize this graph. I showed the result to my teacher and he liked it and asked me if I can build an applet so he can put it in his web site so the other students can use it. I almost know nothing about making an applet. What are my options? is it possible to do such thing?

note that the C++ program itself is not simple.
an output of my program looks like [this](http://postimg.org/image/5qjhlfr6f/).

Comment: Maybe your teacher was confused and thought you were using java. In general you can't run c++ on websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your C++ program some specialized web server, using HTTP server libraries like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt); you might also use [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastcgi) (i.e. make your program become a FastCGI server application), or, if your program is quasi-static and produce simple output and if you accept having a crude web interface, perhaps make it use old [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface)

Of course you need to learn more about Web technologies (e.g. on [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/) - which is not perfect). You need to learn [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) with a bit of [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [Javascript](http://www.javascriptsource.com/tutorials/) (perhaps with [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)) & [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), [Html5 Canvas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element), perhaps [WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL). Google browsers also have [Native Client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Native_Client) (NaCl).

<sup>But all this requires a significant amount of work (weeks or perhaps months; if you do it, please publish your software as free software)</sup>

BTW, you might be interested in [graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) ...